# Calculating Days between days for different columns

Tags: excel, if-statement

I apologize in advance. I am horrible at IF statements. I have a spreadsheet that has three different columns (H, I, J) where someone could put a date. If there is a date put in H, I, or J it would calculate the number of days between column H (I or J) and column C. The number of days returned, would go in column M.

I have tried =IF(H2="",,ABS(H2-C2,OR(I2="",,ABS(I2-C2,OR(J2="",,ABS(J2-C2)))))) However, it gives me an error stating I put too many arguments in.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formula in `M1`: `=IF(H1<>"",ABS(H1-C1),IF(I1<>"",ABS(I1-C1),IF(J1<>"",ABS(J1-C1))))`

[image]